# Помогите найти ошибку в этой задаче

Tags: c++

Задание:

> Есть 2 слова, первое длиннее второго, в первом слове заменить часть
>   слова вторым

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
    string a, b;
    cout << "Enter first word" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Enter second word" << endl;
    cin >> b;
    if( sizeof(a) <= sizeof(b) ) 
        cout << "Error";
    else 
        a = b + copy(sizeof(b) + 1, sizeof(a) - sizeof(b), a);
    cout << a;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(a)` **всегда** равно `sizeof(b)`. А вот `a.size()` может и не быть равно `b.size()`... Только вы же вроде хотели недавно заменять часть *более короткого слова* более длинным, нет?

Comment: @Harry ну прям так всегда) ситуации разные бывают

Comment: @pavel Для `string a, b;`, понятно.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main() {
    string a, b;
    cout << "Enter first word" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Enter second word" << endl;
    cin >> b;

    if (a.size() < b.size()) {
        cout << "Error";
    }
    else {
        a.replace(0, b.size(), b);
        cout << a;
    }
}
```